# manually trigger observable to run again using last value

Tags: rxjs

I have an observable containing all data. I want to create a new observable which will return the filteredData.

So the filtering part must run if the data or global filter changes.
then I started like:

```
function setFilter(filter) {
  this.filter = filter;
}

this.filteredData = this.data.pipe(map(todos => {
    // the filtering inside here will only run if data changed.
    // and not if "this.filter" changes..
  })
);
```

But the problem was it did just returned the filtererData if the data changed and not if the filter changed.

So I found the following solution:

```
function setFilter(filter) {
  this.filter = filter;
  this._filterSub.next(1);
}

this.filteredData = combineLatest(this.data, filterObs, (data, filter) => {
  // this works but I've got the feeling that there is a nicer way
}
```

Now this works but just because I made another unnecessary `BehaviorSubject` and abuse it to trigger the "filtering part".

Isn't there a better cleaner way?

Comment: Your `filter` itself will have to be an observable, else how are you going to "observe" the change of the filter?

Comment: I don't want the `filter` to be an observable, because the filter values are coming from an angular component and when using `setFilter` it's not only for running the filters also for caching the filterValues, so when you navigate away and come back, the filterInputs are still the same.

Comment: you do not want the filter to be an observable, yet you want to react to it when the filter changes...not sure if I fully understand your requirement though. If you are using angular reactive forms, you can listen to the `form`'s `.valueChanges()` though.

Comment: haha sorry, but digging into rxjs is a bit much at the beginning and makes me to not know what I want ;) Ok, I was searching for something like `this.filteredData.next()` but instead of emitting a new value just emit again the last value, so it would run again through the `filtering part`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is to user `ReplaySubject`. Either as your `data` field or as the target of the `pipe`:

```
const filtered = new ReplaySubject(1);
// ... your other code, including updating the filter
this.data.filter(<filter>).subscribe(filtered);
```